# How do you update something in an SKAction while using repeat repeatForever?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

As you'll see below, I'm trying to update the `durationNumber`, so that the `colorSwitch` object turns faster. The `durationNumber` does update, but `colorSwitch` doesn't rotate faster. How do I accomplish this?

```
func turnWheel() {
    var durationNumber = 2.0

    let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: durationNumber)

    let switchAction = SKAction.run {
        if let newState = SwitchState(rawValue: self.switchState.rawValue + 1) {
            self.switchState = newState
        } else {
            self.switchState = .green
        }
        if self.score > self.scoreCheck {
            self.scoreCheck += 1
            durationNumber *= 0.5
        }
    }
    colorSwitch.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([rotateAction, switchAction])))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not update your `duration`, instead update your `speed`

```
func turnWheel() {
    var durationNumber = 2.0

    let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: durationNumber)

    let switchAction = SKAction.run {
        if let newState = SwitchState(rawValue: self.switchState.rawValue + 1) {
            self.switchState = newState
        } else {
            self.switchState = .green
        }
        if self.score > self.scoreCheck {
            self.scoreCheck += 1
            colorSwitch.speed *= 2  
        }
    }
    colorSwitch.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([rotateAction, switchAction])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the value of the local variable, but not changing the `SKAction` object itself.  You need to change `rotateAction.duration` to have any effect on the action itself.

```
if self.score > self.scoreCheck {
    self.scoreCheck += 1
    durationNumber *= 0.5
    rotateAction.duration = durationNumber
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!